# NSTimer fails to invoke methord

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, nstimer

Following is my sample code.

```
@interface TrackTimer : NSObject {

    NSTimer *timer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;

- (void) startTimer;
- (void) stopTimer;
- (void) timerFired;

@end


TrackTimer.m

@synthesize timer;

- (void) startTimer
{

NSLog(@"Timer started ...");

if(timer)
{
    timer = nil;    
}
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

- (void) stopTimer
{

NSLog(@"Timer stoped ...");
[tTimer invalidate];

}


- (void) timerFired
{

   NSLog(@"Timer Fired ... :)");    
}
```

I have to use the same timer object from 3 different view controllers, my problem is `startTimer` method do not invoke `timerFired` method in 2nd UIViewController. Its works perfectly on 1st and 3rd View Controller.

appln Flow : 1stView -> 2ndView -> 3rdView

Comment: I've added a link to the end of my post. Youl'll just need to see what you did wrong. Believe me, sometimes the mistake is so unnoticeable that you can go crazy trying to catch it. I once remember declaring an NSRange as a pointer and then wasting tons of time to see where my mistake was.

Comment: FINALLY SOLVED : I added NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]; before calling my start timer method and than added [runloop run];  code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know how you do that, but NStimer has a class method called
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats. So you can do it like this:

```
 timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self 
                                               selector:@selector(timerFired)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
```

This will invoke the timerFired method for you.

P.S.Here's the link to a simple app that does just what you want.

http://www.mediafire.com/?8uz115drqzb2nan

Comment: I m using the same method but the timer is not getting fired after my time interval of 30sec.

Comment: I cannot figure out the reason for the problem if I don't see the code. Could you please post the code, in fact the whole code inside TrackTimer class. I'd like to see where and how you validate the timer.

Comment: I have added .m code. This code properly works when my class inherits from UIViewController.

Comment: I see you've set the timer to not repeat. It means the timer will not reschedule itself to fire again and again unless it's invalidated. Don't you get it fired even once? Try to set the interval to 2 seconds and repeats to YES.

Comment: Actually, I don't want timer to repeat again n again.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right... almost.
Your timer does not fire, because of the "if" statement.

```
if (timer) {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(boom) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Here, the "if" statement returns NO, because the timer is not yet initialized..
The fact that you make it a property and synthesize it does not mean that (timer != nil)

If you remove the "if" statement it should work...

Comment: I have already kept timer code outside the if loop. (see my post)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) on NSTimer:

```
The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must have the following signature:
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```

So, it looks like the signature of your timerFired method needs to be expanded to include one parameter '(NSTimer*)theTimer' and your selector needs to be @selector(timerFired:)

Comment: My code for timer works fine on 1st & 3rd view controller in both cases. i.e. My current implementation & with your suggestion to include NSTimer as parameter. Some how its not working on 2nd view(In both cases).

Comment: JITesh61: when is startTimer and stopTimer getting invoked in the 3 respective view controllers?  What's different (other than the timer doesn't work) about the implementation or the flow of the 2nd controller?

Comment: The problem got solved, I have added NSRunLoop code in 2nd View. also, I have updated my original post with the solution.